# How do I access BIOS PACKARD BELL ENTG71BM?

Tags: laptop, usb, bios

I need to boot from a USB stick but can't enter BIOS. I've tried all keys, the laptop requires FN to pressed to use F1-12.

Found the manual, it states that F2 should be used to enter BIOS and activate the F12 Boot menu. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Dont you get BIOS Screen when you power on the System.  F2 should work. Once its power On. Press ESC button (BIOS INFO WILL APPEAR ON SCREEN) and hitting the BIOS SETUP Key as per info

Comment: Try with a different keyboard?!

Comment: ESC doesn't do anything. No info on bios key. I don't have access to another keyboard, might get one later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to get one. But adding a different keyboard helped and the F2 button does access the BIOS.

Comment: F2 on built in keyboard worked for me