# How do i enter BIOS mode on a Packard Bell P5WS0?

Tags: laptop

I need to boot from a usb stick and don’t know how to enter bios mode. I’ve tried to press esc and f2 because i read that somewhere but nothing works. Please help me.

Comment: Do not read it "somewhere", read it in the user's manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access BIOS PACKARD BELL ENTG71BM?](https://superuser.com/questions/1230504/how-do-i-access-bios-packard-bell-entg71bm)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia i don’t have the user manual it’s a old pc

Comment: Should be the same as the model in the link above. And you have to spam the key immediately after powering on.

Comment: Packard Bell is F1 or Delete key to enter bios....https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=58779

Answer (score 0):

Most used hotkeys (in my experience) to enter the BIOS are:

- DEL
- F12
- F2
- F10

In the ancient past I have also seen:

- F5
- F8
- F1